# Python format date string from postgresql db

Tags: python, postgresql, timestamp

I have the following code that extracts a postgres CURRENT_TIMESTAMP from a database

```
cursor.execute("SELECT submitdate FROM journeys WHERE display = true")
submitDate = cursor.fetchone()['submitdate']
```

which returns

```
2015-08-11 12:44:31.790462
```

How would I format this to show as `11-08-2015` for example?

I've read about and tried things such as this but they don't work

```
print(
    datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
        int("1284101485")
    ).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
)
```

Comment: submitDate.strftime("%d-%m-%y")

Comment: He wants `11-08-2015 ` then it shoud be submitDate.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution that worked comes from Abhis's comment above.

```
submitDate.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
```